# body {background: url(image.png)} won't center or adapt to navigator size?

Tags: html, css, firefox, background, positioning

So I have a basic school project and a samll bug is really annoying me... been at it for a few hours nows..

I need a background that looks like this:
[image]

It is specified that I must add the background image to my body element, so here is what I did in my CSS stylesheet:

```
body {
background: no-repeat url(background.jpg);
background-position: center center;
background-color: #f2f2f2; }
```

All the other rules you see were specified by the teacher.
Here is what it gives on Firefox:
[image]

First off it's too large for the navigator compared to the background image in the teachers example. Second it isn't centered..

Any kind of help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: check background-cover

Comment: Use `background: #f2f2f2 url(background.jpg) no-repeat center center;` and delete `background-position`, and `background-color`.

Comment: Tried background-size: cover; and does not work for me

Comment: @SatoTakeru tried it and gives me the same result haha maybe something is wrong with my css or something

Comment: What do you want it to look like on different viewport aspect ratios? Is it to be cropped where necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think what is missing is:

```css
body {
  background: no-repeat url(background.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center center;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

The `background-attachment` property sets whether a background image scrolls with the rest of the page, or is fixed. and the `background-size` property specifies the size of the background images, `cover` Resize the background image to cover the entire container.

Comment: This one worked perfectly, thank you!